# How to name files to easily insert something in the middle?

Tags: filesystems, file-management

I have a directory of files that are consequent scenes of a complete video.

```
└── 01-feat
    ├── 00-home-scroll.mp4
    ├── 01-page-home.mp4
    ├── 02-page-about.mp4
    ├── 03-page-contact.mp4
    ├── 04-page-pricing.mp4
    ├── 05-page-sign-in.mp4
    ├── 06-page-sign-up.mp4
    ├── 07-page-newsletter.mp4
    ├── 08-page-terms.mp4
    ├── 09-page-privacy.mp4
    ├── 10-signup.mp4
    ├── 11-pricing.mp4
    ├── 12-checkout-success.mp4
    ├── 12-stripe-checkout.mp4
    ├── 13-stripe-billing.mp4
    ├── poster.jpg
    └── video.md
```

I need it like this for the [Narakeet text-to-speach tool](https://www.narakeet.com/), to generate a separate audio over every scene.

In the *video.md* file, I've got:

```
---
(video:
  file: 00-home-scroll.mp4
  segment: end)
Let's see an example Ruby on Rails project generated via Hix.

---
(video:
  file: 01-page-home.mp4)

On the homepage we can see the basic Navbar and Footer layout. This example was configured to use Tailwind, but it also works for the Bootstrap and Bulma frameworks.
```

and so on.

Now, at some point I'd like to extend my video by inserting a scene in between *04-page-contact* and *04-page-pricing*. At this point, I'd need to rename every reference from `04-` to the last prefix in my *video.md*.

One non-scaling solution to this problem that comes to mind is using more-advanced prefixes, for example:

```
└── 01-feat
    ├── 0000-home-scroll.mp4
    ├── 0100-page-home.mp4
    ├── 0200-page-about.mp4
    ├── 0300-page-contact.mp4
    ├── 0400-page-pricing.mp4
    ├── 0500-page-sign-in.mp4
    ├── ...
    ├── poster.jpg
    └── video.md
```

That allows me to insert *0301-page-billing* file (and up to 98 other files). It's not bad, but I figured I'll ask here before commiting to it, in case someone has a better idea.

Comment: You could start 100, 200… but when you get to 1000, 1100 etc it might depend on whether your OS uses natural sorting or not - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMD7t.png - check whether or not that works.

Comment: Many "correct" ways to go about it, there's no "best" one for sure. Just go for whatever feels the most comfortable for your use case.

Comment: @Destroy666 - no, there aren't *many* ways. it all depends entirely on how your system sorts. if it sorts 1, 11, 100, 2 then you need to test if it can manage with leading zeros, 010, 011, 020. If it natural-sorts, then the world is your oyster.

Comment: There are still many ways regardless of sorting, e.g. `04-01`, `04_01`, `04a`, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I might have gone overeager with using the word "best" in the question title. I simply wanted to know if there's a solution that's **better** than my idea.

Comment: All of those would respond in different ways, depending on how the OS sorts. If you start dropping dashes in the middle  then you break the sorting in different ways depending on OS - https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5QHm.png

Comment: Sure, but I'm more concerned about the need to edit multiple entries in the _video.md_ file than about file system sorting - as you point out yourself, I cannot please everyone there.

Comment: See how both Mac & Windows respond well to the 100, 101, 200, 1100 scheme, whereas they both make mistakes - but *different* mistakes for other schemes. Maybe not 'mistakes' but definitely 'differences of opinion'.

Comment: I've voted to reopen this. Just from a couple of simple experiments you can see there's really quite a simple 'best', at least for Mac & Win. 'Best' being defined as "the simplest system that actually works"

Comment: Oh, dammit. Windows ***still*** can't do proper natural sort… look how easily it breaks, change one file name from test to best & it's lost it already. https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4SVN.png

Comment: Leading zeroes seems to help it again realise they're all *numbers* - https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQH5N.png

Comment: I admire your dedication to solving this problem mate, thanks.

Comment: Welcome:) tbh, every time I have to use Windows I find another of these irritating little quirks that drives me absolutely bonkers… so this was as much for my 'edutainment' as yours ;)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a good bit of empirical testing, cross-platform between Mac & Windows, it looks like the OPs 'non-scaling' solution actually might scale best of all.

```
└── 01-feat
    ├── 0000-home-scroll.mp4
    ├── 0100-page-home.mp4
    ├── 0101-extra-page-home.mp4
    ├── 0200-page-about.mp4
    ├── 0300-page-contact.mp4
    ├── 0400-page-pricing.mp4
    ├── 0500-page-sign-in.mp4
    ├── . . . 
    ├── 01000-page-sign-in1.mp4
    ├── 01001-page-sign-in2.mp4
    ├── 01100-page-sign-in2.mp4
    ├── . . .
    ├── poster.jpg
    └── video.md
```

Numbering in hundreds, with a leading zero even after you pass 1000, rather than keeping the character count the same.
This allows you to insert up to 99 pages between existing numbers, doesn't break if the alphabetical suffix changes, & carries to over 1000 successfully… on both Mac & Windows.

Not using the leading zero breaks on Windows, though is OK on Mac - not good enough for me;) [Presumably would also work in tens, for 9 insert pages, but didn't empirically test that.] Many of the other schemes tested break on one or the other due to the different way each sorts.

Testing image of some of the trial candidates

[image]